# wildfly-8.1.0.Final Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8, initial-context

im getting following Error

```
**ERROR:**

2014-10-07 16:33:46,692 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.naming.NamingException: 
 JBAS011843: **Failed instantiate** **InitialContextFactory 
 org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory** from classloader 
 ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.wildfly8.1.ear.wildfly8.1-war.war:main"
 from Service Module Loader [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from [Module
 "deployment.wildfly8.1.ear.wildfly8.1-war.war:main" from Service Module Loader]]
```

Code:

```
final Properties env = new Properties();

env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "127.0.0.1");
//OR env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
context = new InitialContext(env);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to the `META-INF` of the top level **.ear** file. In the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` add a dependency for `org.jboss.remote-naming` and `org.jboss.ejb-client`.

Here's some documentation on `jboss-deployment-strucure.xml`: [Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)

Other useful links:

[EJB invocations from a remote server instance](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance)
[ejb-multi-server: EJB Communication Across Servers](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/ejb-multi-server)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include in your war/WEB-INF/lib directory all dependencies of a remote client:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. but i dont want add libs in war. only server itself. so what are remote lib needs to add in server ?

Comment: Download the bom: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:get -Dartifact=org.wildfly:wildfly-jms-client-bom:${version.wildfly}:pom -Ddest=. -U` go to the `dependencies` sections and see